# How can I use jquery to play audio with a toggling play and pause button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

I'm new to javascript. This probably isn't the right way to go about what i'm trying to achieve but, as the title says, I'm trying to play an audio file and toggle between two images which act as the pause and play button. Below is what I have so far, I can't seem to get the pause button to hide and the play button to show.

```
var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'audio/track.mp3');
audioElement.setAttribute('autoplay', 'autoplay');
//audioElement.load()
$.get();
audioElement.addEventListener("load", function() {
audioElement.play();
}, true);

if (audioElement.paused) {
        audioElement.play();
        $('.pause').show();
        $('.play').hide();
    } 
else {
        audioElement.pause();
        $('.play').show();
        $('.pause').hide();
    }


$('.play').click(function() {
audioElement.play();
});


$('.pause').click(function() {
audioElement.pause();
```

Would someone be able to point out where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Check my answer below. Is that what you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you're missing an extra `});` at the end of the code.

I don't know if you want to play the audio on page load or on click of a button, as you didn't specified that, that's why I will provide you two different ways of implementing, first who starts the audio on page load and second that starts the audio playing on click of a button (also using `new Audio` instead of `createElement(audio)`). Both ways are great.

If you want to do it your way you could add event listeners for `playing` and `paused`. This is a way to do it:

```js
var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
audioElement.id = 'audio-player';
audioElement.controls = 'controls';
audioElement.autoplay = 'autoplay';
audioElement.src = 'http://www.archive.org/download/bolero_69/Bolero.mp3';
audioElement.type = 'audio/mpeg';

audioElement.addEventListener('playing', function() {
  $('.pause').css('display', 'inline-block');
  $('.play').hide();
}, false);

audioElement.addEventListener('paused', function() {
  $('.pause').hide();
  $('.play').css('display', 'inline-block');
}, false);

$('.play').on('click', function() {
  $(this).hide();
  $('.pause').css('display', 'inline-block');
  audioElement.play();
});

$('.pause').on('click', function() {
  $(this).hide();
  $('.play').css('display', 'inline-block');
  audioElement.pause();
});
```

```css
.play,
.pause {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.play {
  background: transparent url('https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-messaging-productivity-1/128/play-icon-2-128.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.pause {
  background: transparent url('https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/material-audio-video/20/pause-circle-outline-128.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class='play'></span>
<span class='pause'></span>
```

Another simple way would be to use `new Audio()`:

```js
var audioElement = new Audio('http://www.archive.org/download/bolero_69/Bolero.mp3');

$('.play').on('click', function() {
  $(this).hide();
  $('.pause').css('display', 'inline-block');
  audioElement.play();
});

$('.pause').on('click', function() {
  $(this).hide();
  $('.play').css('display', 'inline-block');
  audioElement.pause();
});
```

```css
.play,
.pause {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.play {
  background: transparent url('https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-messaging-productivity-1/128/play-icon-2-128.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.pause {
  background: transparent url('https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/material-audio-video/20/pause-circle-outline-128.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class='play'></span>
<span class='pause'></span>
```

Comment: Thank you. The former was what I was looking to implement. This way makes a lot sense

Comment: Awesome. Happy to help.